# How to make small multidimensional array from big multidimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

**I have a large multidimensional array like this**

```
Array
(
    [/] => Array
        (
            [0] => d:Cover & Label:0
            [1] => d:INFO TBS:0
            [2] => d:VIDEO TS:0
        )

    [/Cover & Label/] => Array
        (
            [0] => f:This Is 40 (2012) cover.jpg:197602
            [1] => f:This Is 40 (2012) label.jpg:274893
            [2] => f:This Is 40 (2012) poster.jpg:50100
        )

    [/INFO TBS/] => Array
        (
            [0] => f:This Is 40 (2012) INFORMATIE .txt:1333
            [1] => f:Torrent Downloaded from SilverTorrents.me.txt:41
            [2] => f:Torrent downloaded from Demonoid.com.txt:47
            [3] => f:Torrent_downloaded_from_AhaShare.com.txt:107
            [4] => f:Tracked by H33T.com.txt:19
            [5] => f:silver torrent logo.jpg:64109
            [6] => f:tracked By movie-torrentz.txt:36
        )

    [/VIDEO TS/] => Array
        (
            [0] => f:VIDEO_TS.BUP:12288
            [1] => f:VIDEO_TS.IFO:12288
            [2] => f:VIDEO_TS.VOB:59392
            [3] => f:VTS_01_0.BUP:18432
            [4] => f:VTS_01_0.IFO:18432
            [5] => f:VTS_01_0.VOB:59392
            [6] => f:VTS_01_1.VOB:39620608
            [7] => f:VTS_02_0.BUP:88064
            [8] => f:VTS_02_0.IFO:88064
            [9] => f:VTS_02_0.VOB:59392
            [10] => f:VTS_02_1.VOB:1073709056
            [11] => f:VTS_02_2.VOB:1073709056
            [12] => f:VTS_02_3.VOB:1073709056
            [13] => f:VTS_02_4.VOB:1073709056
            [14] => f:VTS_02_5.VOB:295792640
        )

)
```

**How can i create a smaller sized array like this one.**

```
Array
(
    [/] => Array
        (
            [0] => d:Cover & Label:0
            [1] => d:INFO TBS:0
            [2] => d:VIDEO TS:0
        )

    [/Cover & Label/] => Array
        (
            [0] => f:This Is 40 (2012) cover.jpg:197602
            [1] => f:This Is 40 (2012) label.jpg:274893
            [2] => f:This Is 40 (2012) poster.jpg:50100
        )
)
```

i want to create a smaller array whose, strlen of  json_encoded($array) <= 255

**so far i have managed to do this,**

```
<?php
$small_array_new = array();
foreach($DATA as $key => $mini_array){

        foreach($mini_array as $mini_array_element){

                if(strlen(json_encode($small_array_new)) <= 255){
                $small_array_new[$key][] = $mini_array_element;
                }

                if(strlen(json_encode($small_array_new)) > 255){
                array_pop($small_array_new[$key] );
                break;
                }
            }
}
```

**But this is not stopping after the strlen is reached to 255 and break isnt breaking out completely and giving me output like this.**

```
Array
(
    [/] => Array
        (
            [0] => d:Cover & Label:0
            [1] => d:INFO TBS:0
            [2] => d:VIDEO TS:0
        )

    [/Cover & Label/] => Array
        (
            [0] => f:This Is 40 (2012) cover.jpg:197602
            [1] => f:This Is 40 (2012) label.jpg:274893
            [2] => f:This Is 40 (2012) poster.jpg:50100
        )

    [/INFO TBS/] => Array
        (
        )

    [/VIDEO TS/] => Array
        (
            [0] => f:VIDEO_TS.BUP:12288
        )

)
```

**How can i make it break once the strlen(json_encode($$small_array_new)) > 255 ?**

---

**UPDATE : after using break 2;**

```
Array
(
    [/] => Array
        (
            [0] => d:Cover & Label:0
            [1] => d:INFO TBS:0
            [2] => d:VIDEO TS:0
        )

    [/Cover & Label/] => Array
        (
            [0] => f:This Is 40 (2012) cover.jpg:197602
            [1] => f:This Is 40 (2012) label.jpg:274893
            [2] => f:This Is 40 (2012) poster.jpg:50100
        )

    [/INFO TBS/] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

Comment: are you trying to store into the database?? is there problem with database table colum?

Comment: yes, i am trying to store the smaller array in the database , and database table column is char(255), thats the reason i want to break it after length is 255 and there are few reasons i am not using the bigger field

Comment: okay noted .. do you need each parent node from actual array ?? with its minimal content .. like you mentioned you don't need empty one `[/INFO TBS/] => Array`

Comment: @bhushya no, i dont need empty arrays .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass number of loops to be stopped to [`break`](http://www.php.net/break) statement.

You want to break both `foreach` loops, so use `break 2;`.

---

**EDIT**
I see.. You have to remove the last array when it's empty. You can use for example

```
if(strlen(json_encode($small_array_new)) > 255){
    array_pop($small_array_new[$key] );
    if (count($small_array_new[$key]) == 0) unset($small_array_new[$key]);
    break 2;
}
```

Comment: tried that , but still adding empty array at the end., thanks

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you YaLinqo library from Athari (or other LINQ libraries). It does such tasks with one line of code.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out a small function doing this for n-dimensional arrays

```
function junkArray2Json($data, $len = 255, &$scope = null, &$root = null)
{
    if (!is_array($data)) {
        $scope = $data;
        return $scope;
    }

    if ($isInitialCall = is_null($root)) {
        $root = array();
        $scope = &$root;
    } else {
        $scope = array();
    }

    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        $rootCopy = unserialize(serialize($root));
        $scopeCopy = unserialize(serialize($scope));
        junkArray2Json($value, $len, $scope[$key], $root);

        if (empty($scope[$key])) {
            unset($scope[$key]);
        }

        if (strlen(json_encode($root)) > $len) {
            $root = $rootCopy;
            $scope = $scopeCopy;
        }
    }

    return $scope;
}

print_r(junkArray2Json($DATA, 255));
```

this prints

```
Array
(
    [/] => Array
        (
            [0] => d:Cover & Label:0
            [1] => d:INFO TBS:0
            [2] => d:VIDEO TS:0
        )

    [/Cover & Label/] => Array
        (
            [0] => f:This Is 40 (2012) cover.jpg:197602
            [1] => f:This Is 40 (2012) label.jpg:274893
            [2] => f:This Is 40 (2012) poster.jpg:50100
        )

    [/VIDEO TS/] => Array
        (
            [0] => f:VIDEO_TS.BUP:12288
        )

)
```